# Unable to pass eVar value when use s.tl as send beacon

Tags: adobe, analytics, adobe-analytics

Would like to get some help over here regarding Adobe Analytics
I am not able to get the value I've set for eVar13 when I chose send beacon s.tl
`s.tl(): Send data to Adobe Analytics and do not treat it as a page view`  but when choose s.t `s.t(): Send data to Adobe Analytics and treat it as page view`, eVar13 works fine and able to get what i want

here's my code to set variable when click on some button:

```
        s.pageName = 'campaign:help-page';
        s.eVar13 = s.pageName;
        s.eVar31 = "Policy File";
        setEvent("event4");
        s.linkTrackVars = "eVar13,eVar31,events";
        s.linkTrackEvents = "event4";
```

I even console logged the s.eVar13 and s.pageName
both of them showed  `campaign:help-page`

Answer (score 0):

Send beacon in custom code only.

```
s.tl(thi,"o", s.eVar13 );
```

Detailed information [tl-method - Adobe](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/analytics/implementation/vars/functions/tl-method.html?lang=en)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).